# UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires jquery ScriptResourceMapping when using ScriptBundle

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the new [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097384) in ASP.NET 4.5 **Web Forms** application. UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a jquery ScriptResourceMapping to work, but I'm registering it through the ScriptBundle config.

I'm using like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts").Include("~/Content/jquery-1.9.0.js"));
```

But this generates an error:

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

To fixing the error, this:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition { Path = "~/Content/jquery-1.9.0.js" });
```

But I want to use Bundling and Minification to combine and minimize all application scripts (in this example I use just jquery file to be more simple). What's the best solution to this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a solution, works with Bundle and Minification, but I don't know if is the best.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts")
    .Include("~/Content/jquery-1.9.0.js")
    .Include("..."));

ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition { Path = "~/Content/Scripts" });
```

ScriptResourceDefinition.Path is the same as ScriptBundle virtual path.